# How to create a Proxy that can compose methods of more than one class?

Tags: java, proxy, cglib, object-composition

I have class `A` that implements interface `I`. I have two classes `B` and `C`, each extends `A` and adds a new method. The new method in Class `B` is different from that of `C`. I need to create a Proxy (sort of composite) that should have all the methods of `A` and the new methods in `B` and `C`.

I tried to use Mixin$Generator in CGLIB but I get Error `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate interface name in class file`.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: doesn't make sense to me, if C and B overrid a method in A, what implementation of the overridden method should be called in the proxy?

Comment: How are the new methods different? Do they have the same signature?

Comment: @yazanjaber C and B do not override any method in A.

Comment: @PM 77-1 The new method in B and C have different signature.

Comment: Is this new method **the only** difference between `C` and `B`?

Comment: Yes. The new method is the only difference between C and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to truly compose two non-interface classes in Java. If those two objects have a common structure (by `A`), then this would result in a conflict since any field or method in `A` would be doubled what is illegal in Java. However, if there is no such conflicting information present, then the classes `B` and `C` should not share a super class `A`.

If you want to apply this sort of mixin delegation, you will need to create some interface abstraction for your classes. These interfaces can then be combined inside a proxy and delegate to the instances of `B` and `C` depending on which of those implement an interface. This, and nothing more, is offered by cglib's `Mixin`. Here is an example of how the composition with cglib works:

```
public interface Interface1 {
  String first();
}

public interface Interface2 {
  String second();
}

public class Class1 implements Interface1 {
  @Override
  public String first() {
    return "first";
  }
}

public class Class2 implements Interface2 {
  @Override
  public String second() {
    return "second";
  }
}

public interface MixinInterface extends Interface1, Interface2 { /* empty */ }

@Test
public void testMixin() throws Exception {
  Mixin mixin = Mixin.create(new Class[]{Interface1.class, Interface2.class,
      MixinInterface.class}, new Object[]{new Class1(), new Class2()});
  MixinInterface mixinDelegate = (MixinInterface) mixin;
  assertEquals("first", mixinDelegate.first());
  assertEquals("second", mixinDelegate.second());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. A is provided by a framework and the framework expects  only one subclass of A. I have a situation where I can have more than one subclass of A and I need to create a composite dynamically.

Comment: Why do you need cglib for that? Just write a delegator implementation of `A` and delegate to the appropriate instance. If your answer is solved, consider marking my answer as accepted. Thanks!